# "Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" should have Yes/No

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

I saw this in the comments on my latest question:

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

Clicking the second sentence starts a new chat automatically, and this I didn't want to do.

We need a YES/NO option.

Comment: Agreed. I have clicked it by mistake too many times, intending to write new comment.